# Menu responsivo bootstrap não fecha ao clicar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-3, menu

Gostaria de saber por qual motivo o menu bootstrap nos dispositivos móveis não fecha ao clicar no menu. Ele abre normalmente, mas se o usuário quiser fechar, o mesmo não fecha.

link de acesso: www.paddock.eco.br

Código do Menu:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav id="topNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar">
           <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>  
       </div>
       <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="bs-navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">SERVIÇOS <span class="caret"></span></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#one">Detalhamento Automotivo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#two">Polimento Paddock</a></li>
      <li><a href="#three">Pacotes Carro</a></li>
      <li><a href="#four">Pacotes Moto</a></li> 
              </ul>
        </li>
           <li>
              <a class="page-scroll" href="#last">Contatos</a>
           </li>
         </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: 1° parte do menu acima desse que postei acima. <nav id="topNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                
            </div>

Comment: Você pode editar sua resposta e colocar esse código que está em seu comentário...

Comment: Qual versão do jQuery você está usando? Na verdade o toggle da classe `navbar-collapse collapse in` no elemento `bs-navbar` parece estar com bug - a classe `collapse in` não mantém a alteração para `collapse out`.

Comment: Muda o data-target para data-target=".collapse" e pode apagar id="bs-navbar"

Comment: @RenanBessa edite sua pergunta e coloque como resposta junto com o código para ter um fácil entendimento.

Answer (score 1):

Olha, esse erro se dá pela versão do bootstrap e a versão do JS.
 Use a versão solicitada na documentação e não a que você já tem em seu projeto.

```html
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim e Respond.js para suporte no IE8 de elementos HTML5 e media queries -->
    <!-- ALERTA: Respond.js não funciona se você visualizar uma página file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Olá, mundo!</h1>

    <!-- jQuery (obrigatório para plugins JavaScript do Bootstrap) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Inclui todos os plugins compilados (abaixo), ou inclua arquivos separadados se necessário -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```